# How to display contents from a sequel database connection in the view file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, sequel

I am trying to retrieve data from a PostgreSQL database with Sequel in Sinatra.

> DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://connection_data')
>       items = DB[:items]

Then I try to get an entry with a specific ID:

```
get '/:id' do
   @item = items.filter(:id => params[:id]) 
   erb :edit
end
```

In my edit view I would like to display the content of the @item variable. The problem is that I don´t know how to get for example the ID.

```
<% if @item %>
   <a href="/<%= @item.id %>/doit">Do something</a>
<% else %>
   <p>Item not found.</p>
<% end %>
```

I tried using @item.id and @item[:id] but both don´t work. I get an error `undefined method 'id' for  #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset:0x007fac118b7120>`. What would be the right way to retrieve the values from the @item variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@item = items.filter(:id => params[:id])` returns a dataset.  If you want a single item, you should do: `@item = items.first(:id => params[:id].to_i)`

Also `@item.id` is probably not want you want.  Given that `items = DB[:items]`, you are using a plain dataset and then `@item = items.first(:id => params[:id].to_i)` is going to give you a hash.  You need to do `@item[:id]` to get the item's id.

You may want to look at using models instead:

```
# model file
class Item < Sequel::Model; end

# sinatra code
@item = Item[params[:id].to_i]

# template
@item.id
```

Comment: Thank you, in your example where would I put the part where I create the dataset?

Comment: Do you know where I could find an example of how to manage a project? Because somehow I have the feeling everyone does in a different way. Some don´t use models at all for example...

Answer (score 0):

Actually `@item.id` is the right way. The only problem I can see in your code is

```
@item = items.filter(:id == params[:id])
```

which should be

```
@item = items.filter(:id => params[:id].to_i)
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
@item = items.where(:id => params[:id].to_i)

@item.select(:id) #to embed
```

params[:id] is giving a string, so convert it to an integer.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but I still get an error "undefined method 'id' for #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset:0x007fac118b7120>

Comment: Could you post your table description? It may seem like a silly questions but are you sure that the 'items' table has an 'id' attribute?

Comment: Yes I am sure, my table consist of three columns, "id", "name" and "price" and it has three rows. Counting my data or calculating the average just works fine, so the data is actually there.

Comment: Same error, I forgot to mention that I am using Heroku to deploy my files. When I tried to find out what type params[:id] is by using .type I got this weird error message: `NoMethodError - undefined method 'type' "favicon.ico":String` it seems as if `id` is a string containing "favicon.ico". How is that possible when all I do is open the URL myproject.herokuapp.com/1

Comment: I haven't really worked with Heroku so far, so I can't comment, but that really is odd. Is it possible for you to try running the app locally?

Comment: The error seemed to be due to the id not being an integer but a string. However after converting it to int by using `to_i` I get the error `ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE (("id" = 1) AND (id)) LIMIT 1`. Where does the `AND (id)` part come from? I am confused.

Comment: That should definitely not happen as the .to_i method returns a single value only. I would suggest asking on Sequel's mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sequel-talk